# Traversing Nested JSON file with json.simple

Tags: java, json

I am new to JSON and I am learning using the json.simple library. I can't figure out how to access the values in the nested objects or arrays. Here is a piece of the JSON file that I am working with:

```
{
   metrics: {
      steps: {
         min: 0,
         max: 140,
         sum: 1161,
         summary: {
            max_steps_per_minute: null,
            min_steps_per_minute: null
         },
         values: [
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
           13,
            0,
            0,
            0,
```

Comment: I recommend you [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library. It's very useful with json having arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course as soon as I asked this I figured it out. In case someone else needs this information here is some of the code to show what I did:

```
public void fileDecode()
    {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try
        {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\JSONData\\test.json");
            Object obj = parser.parse(file);
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)obj;
            JSONObject metrics = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("metrics");
            JSONObject steps = (JSONObject)metrics.get("steps");
            JSONArray values = (JSONArray)steps.get("values");

            Iterator<Integer> iterator = values.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }
            System.out.println(steps.get("min"));
            System.out.println(metrics.get("steps"));
            System.out.println(jsonObject.get("metrics"));

            file.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```